# Place a node and insert its text later

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working on a tikz picture where there are a series of nodes that have to have the same text, but at different locations (placed by a for loop).

The plan is that all nodes along the x axis (with the same y) will have the same label text.

At the moment, I have the nodes placing with empty text, and are named based on the inner for loop (the y axis), with an empty label text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}{
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,3}{
                \draw (\x - 0.5, \y - 0.5) rectangle (\x + 0.5, \y + 0.5);
                \node (node\y) at (\x, \y) {};
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So would there be a way to later set the label text for a given `node\y`?

Edit : There are lots of good answers for this, Torbjorn's answer is the most concise, and gives everything I need.

Comment: You can use coordinate instead of your \node and later use the node with the text in a loop or something. The two commands are `\coordinate (node\y) at (\x,\y);` and `\node at (node\y) {my text};`

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted. Post an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, like `\foreach [count=\y from 0] \txt in {foo,bar,baz}` for the inner loop?

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}{
            \foreach [count=\y from 0] \txt in {foo,bar,baz}{
                \draw (\x - 0.5, \y - 0.5) rectangle (\x + 0.5, \y + 0.5);
                \node (node\x\y) at (\x, \y) {\txt};
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you're not after sequential integers for the y-values, you can use `\foreach \y/\txt in {0/foo,1/bar}` to be able to specify any number. It's less convenient of  course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}{
            \foreach  \y/\txt in {0/foo,1/bar,2/baz}{
                \draw (\x - 0.5, \y - 0.5) rectangle (\x + 0.5, \y + 0.5);
                \node (node\x\y) at (\x, \y) {\txt};
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

like this

it works but you have to have enough space

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}{
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,3}{
                \draw (\x - 0.5, \y - 0.5) rectangle (\x + 0.5, \y + 0.5);
                \node (node\y) at (\x, \y) {};
            }
        }
 \foreach \y in {0,1,...,3}{
 \node at (node\y) { \y};
 }  
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

as you wish (but i don't understand why you like to insert text latter, better is [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t)  approach):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt}]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
            \foreach \y in {0,...,3}{
                \node[box,above right] (n\x\y) at (\x, \y) {};
            }
        }
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
    \node at (n\i 2) {y3};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer your method because I plan to reuse the coordinates in more than one place, and this makes it easy to do so. Thank you!

Comment: @BrydonGibson Well, the nodes are still given names in my example, so you can still do e.g. `\draw (node0) -- (node1);`. `\x` should be added to the node names though, so all nodes are given unique names.

Comment: That is true, I didn't realize I could draw to a node, so that changes the answer